# ImageView Border

Tags: android, android-imageview

I want to arrange border for my image view for my retrieved imaged from sd card and displayed in grid view.My default application looks like images without border like this[image]

But i want to modify it for the screen which should be look like this included images with border
[image]

please give me solution for it.I have posted th code for my ImageAdapter.java

import java.util.ArrayList;

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    public static ArrayList<Images> array=new ArrayList<Images>();

    Context mContext; 
    private LayoutInflater mInflater; 



    public ImageAdapter(Context c,ArrayList<Images> arr) 
    {
        mContext = c;  
        array=arr;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        Log.e("","adapter con");
    }


    public int getCount()
    {
        Log.e("Count",""+array.size());
        return array.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int index)
    {
       // return 0;
        return array.get(index);
    } 

    public long getItemId(int index) 
    {

        return index;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        GridView.LayoutParams layoutParams = new GridView.LayoutParams(80, 80);


        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

        Images i=array.get(position);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(i.getBitmap());

        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imageView.animate();





        return imageView;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

can try .. setBackgroundResource of image view with  padding 2dp ........ make look like same.......

or

as per link found below a more standard way

view_default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />
<padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp"
    android:bottom="1dp" />
</shape>
```

and refer this as well for [set border to imageview dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084930/set-border-to-imageview-dynamically)

v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.view_default);

Comment: even we same question on here as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263611/border-for-an-image-view-in-android

Answer (score 2):

You can set a background in your xml and set padding to your ImageView initially. And later, just call setBackground which will set the background in the way you want.

```
   <ImageView  android:id="@+id/user_image"
    android:layout_width="75dip"
    android:layout_height="75dip"
    android:padding="2dip"
    android:background="ffffff"/>
```

or

```
    image.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
    image.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

then

Set Scale Type like this,

```
image.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon);
```

Comment: I am not taking an imageview from the particular xml file..cauze i implemented the grid view in the main.xml                     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <GridView     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
   />